# "gwmi win32_quickfixengineering" but only need InstalledOn date

Tags: windows, powershell

`gwmi win32_quickfixengineering InstalledOn |sort installedon -desc | select -First 1`

I've tried but that gives me an odd formatting. I simply need to return the installedOn date and maybe the name.

i'm trying to find the most recently installed patch on a system and get that date value.

I've also tried.

`gwmi win32_quickfixengineering |sort installedon -desc | select -First 1`

better formatting but still too much information.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the `InstalledOn` properties, you can use the `-ExpandProperty` option as below.

```
GWMI win32_quickfixengineering | sort -Descending InstalledOn `
    | Select -ExpandProperty InstalledOn -First 1
```

Otherwise you can do something like the below to get a brief overview of the installed KBs.

```
GWMI win32_quickfixengineering | Select HotFixID, InstalledOn, Caption
```

**Info:**

- [Select -ExpandProperty](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/select-expandproperty-propertyname/)
- [Get-HotFix / win32_quickfixengineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix?view=powershell-7)

Comment: That was it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get specific information you want is the following:

Lets say you need a name of a service for a command:

```
$Service = Get-Service Spooler
```

That command would retrieve more information than just the name, but to get the only name, you can type:

```
$Service.name
```

That will return only that value from the saved variable.

So in your case you could do:
(Here you save all the information into a variable)

```
$Quickfix = gwmi win32_quickfixengineering | sort installedon -desc | select -First 1
```

(You can then use that variable to return specific information from that variable)
Then use: `$Quickfix.InstalledOn`

That will return you JUST the date.

Then you could do something like:

`Write-Output "Latest update was $($Quickfix.HotFixID) installed on: $($Quickfix.InstalledOn)`"

That will give you an output of the KB and the date installed. You can of course edit the text, it was just an example.